# How to sync for the emails which are received after a particular email.

Tags: api, email, yahoo

I am working on an application which download Yahoo account emails  in the order of down to top using Yahoo Mail API's.

Application sync logic works like below

Lets say Inbox consists of 1000 emails.

1) Initially fetching 100 emails message ID's by using "ListMessages" with parameters startMid = 0 and numMid=100.
2) Processing chunk emails .
3) Now requesting for the next chunk emails by giving the startMid = 100 and numMid=100.

The above logic works fine if user is not deleting any emails  during syncing.

Is there any way to retrieve next chunk emails based on the message ID (string unique value) rather than message number.

What is the logic for syncing the emails from the last processed message?

PS:I can not rely on  message number (since message number is not meant for unique  identifier of a message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and found "How to get only emails which are arrived from the Client last sync." (http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Yahoo-Mail-Web-Services-API/How-to-get-only-emails-which/1320329478746-16f18e6a-aadd-40c3-b259-e095ce80a1e6) where some guy reply "This feature is not available right now but we do plan to support this in future." date: 3 Nov 2011 11:24 AM

I think you can query mailTables (with YQL) or ListMessage (Api) and get the complete list of messages id (without any info) eg:  SELECT * FROM ymail.messages WHERE numInfo="0"

And then "count" the position of the last message you got and then, get mail from that number. Eg: SELECT * FROM ymail.messages WHERE startMid="3" and numMid="100"

What do you think?
Greetings from Argentina
PS: sorry about my horrible english